# How to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN with a filter that returns the first row in a child table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Assume for a moment I have the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Party] (
    [PartyId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Party] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [PartyId] ASC
    )
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address] (
    [AddressId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PartyId] int NOT NULL,
    [AddressLine1] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [Zip] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Address] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        [AddressId] ASC
    )
)
GO
```

The Party table looks as follows:

```
PartyId DisplayName IsDeleted
1       Party A     0
2       Party B     0
3       Party C     0
4       Party D     0
```

The address as follows:

```
AddressId PartyId AddressLine1     City          State Zip    IsDeleted
1         1       1 Market Street  San Francisco CA    94111  1  
2         1       20 Powell Street San Francisco CA    94111  0  
3         1       3 Davis Street   San Francisco CA    94111  0  
4         2       1 ABC Street     San Francisco CA    94111  1
5         2       NULL             NULL          CA    94111  0   
6         2       NULL             NULL          NULL  NULL   0  
7         2       1 DEF Street     San Francisco CA    94111  0  
8         3       1 XYZ AVE        San Francisco CA    94111  1
```

I'm trying to write a query that would return the following addresses:

```
PartyId AddressLine1     City          State Zip    
1       20 Powell Street San Francisco CA    94111    
2       1 DEF Street     San Francisco CA    94111    
3       NULL             NULL          NULL  NULL    
4       NULL             NULL          NULL  NULL
```

The criteria are to return the first non deleted addresses that are complete for each party, otherwise return NULL.

This is what I tried:

First, I started with a query to give me the party and corresponding addresses that were not deleted. Lets call it Query1.

```
SELECT    
       Party.PartyId,
       Address.AddressLine1,
       Address.City,
       Address.State,
       Address.Zip
FROM        
       Party LEFT OUTER JOIN
       Address ON Party.PartyId = Address.PartyId
WHERE
       (Party.IsDeleted IS NULL OR Party.IsDeleted = 0) AND 
       (Address.IsDeleted IS NULL OR Address.IsDeleted = 0)
ORDER BY
       Party.PartyId desc
```

It does return addresses that are incomplete as well as several rows of addresses that I don't need.

The following query gets rid of the rows other than the first, as well as any incomplete addresses. However, but it also eliminates rows of parties that had no address or incomplete addresses. Lets call it Query2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.PartyId,
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.AddressLine1))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.City))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.State))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.Zip))) > 0 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.AddressLine1))
        ELSE NULL
    END AddressLine1,
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.AddressLine1))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.City))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.State))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.Zip))) > 0 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.City))
        ELSE NULL
    END City,
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.AddressLine1))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.City))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.State))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.Zip))) > 0 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.State))
        ELSE NULL
    END State,
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.AddressLine1))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.City))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.State))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.Zip))) > 0 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(pa.Zip))
        ELSE NULL
    END PostalCode
FROM
    Party p LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            PartyId,
            AddressLine1,
            City,
            State,
            Zip,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY PartyId ORDER BY
                    AddressLine1,
                    City,
                    State,
                    Zip
            ) RowNumber
        FROM
            Address
        WHERE
            LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(AddressLine1))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(City))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(State))) > 0 AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(Zip))) > 0 AND (IsDeleted IS NULL OR IsDeleted = 0)
    ) pa ON p.PartyId = pa.PartyId
    WHERE
        pa.RowNumber = 1 AND (p.IsDeleted IS NULL OR p.IsDeleted = 0) 
    ORDER BY
        PartyId DESC
```

I'm a tad lost as to why the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in Query2 doesn't behave the same as Query1. In essence, why Query2 doesn't parties with invalid addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work. I just tried it by creating the tables and inserting the records as you mentioned.

```
SELECT P.PartyId,
   A.AddressLine1,
   A.City,
   A.State,
   A.PostalCode
FROM Party P
LEFT JOIN (SELECT A1.PartyId,   
        A1.AddressLine1,
                A1.City,
            A1.PostalCode,
            IsDeleted,
                A1.State, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartyId ORDER BY A1.PartyId) AS rownum
FROM [Address] A1
WHERE IsDeleted = 0) A
ON A.PartyId = P.PartyId
AND A.IsDeleted = 0
AND rownum = 1
ORDER BY P.PartyId
```

Comment: It has the same effect a Query2. Party with id 4 is not being returned.

Comment: Ah... I missed that part... I have updated the query above. It should work now. I tried and now get Party with id 4 as well..

Answer (score 0):

So, I was thinking to get list of completed addresses, including address row number, then join the result with tables of parties.

```
WITH cteCompletedAddresses
AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartyId ORDER BY AddressId) as AddressRowNum,
    PartyId, AddressLine1,
    City, State, Zip
  FROM
    Address
  WHERE
    ISNULL(IsDeleted, 0) = 0
    AND LEN(AddressLine1) > 0
    AND LEN(City) > 0
    AND LEN(State) > 0
    AND LEN(Zip) > 0
)
SELECT    
  P.PartyId, P.DisplayName,
  A.AddressLine1,
  A.City, A.State, A.Zip
FROM
  Party P
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cteCompletedAddresses A ON A.PartyId = P.PartyId
WHERE
  A.AddressRowNum = 1
  AND ISNULL(P.IsDeleted, 0) = 0
```

Comment: It only returns one row, namely that of "Party A". The other rows are omitted.

Comment: @WernerStrydom: it returns 2 rows, "Party A" and "Party B", as "Party C" is marked as deleted and "Party D" has no completed address. Please re-check.

Comment: None of the parties are marked as deleted. Note that the criteria includes the statement that if the address is not complete, to return null.  Hence the desired values in the output table.